# Backup SQL Server database to a text file(like .csv) using c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, csv, export-to-csv

I am creating a program that uses a simple database with only a few tables. I need to do a backup and restore of the database to and from a text file like a `.csv`. I have tried a couple of things but none seems to work. Then I came across the following line:

```
 sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("backup database  " + dbname + " to disk='" +
 destdir + "\backup.bak", sqlcon);
```

And I am wondering if I can name it `backup.csv` instead of `.bak`. I would also like to know what to include at the 'using' section. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could name the output file whatever you like, but this will not make it a CSV file.
The SQL Backup script produces a backup in a binary file and could be restored only using the appropriate tools like SQL Server Management Studio or a RESTORE script

You don't have any particular needs for the using section. The `System.Data.SqlClient` is the namespace that contains the classes `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` needed to execute the script

A possible workaround to reach (at least partially) you requirements is to use the [BCP utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).
Usually this utility is required when you need to import large amount of data from a storage medium to your Sql Server database. But the BCP utility could also be used to export data from your database in a text file on disk. However BCP requires the name of a single datatable or a SQL Query that returns a single set of data, so you probably need to call it more than one time.
Notice also that BCP is not a Sql command but a standalone utility installed with SQL Server.

As an example (for a better explanation of the parameters check the link above) you could write this code

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "bcp.exe";
psi.Arguments = @"TableOrQueryToExtract out d:\temp\myTableData.txt -T -d MyDataBaseName -w";
Process.Start(psi);
```

As you can see, you need to call this code for each table you need to export and save that data in separate files on disk (or write a complex program that capture the BCP output and joins everything together. At the end of the day, if you don't have a specific requirement to get a text file, I really suggest to opt for the simplicity of the BACKUP command

Comment: I would also like to use the BACKUP command, but cannot use it as the output needs to be a text base file.

Comment: I have just one small question. When I use the code above (modified) to do import, it adds the data instead of overwriting it. Any suggestion?

Comment: Usually I import the data in a separate table and join with the original one using a ad-how stored procedure. You can also issue a TRUNCATE TABLE 'tablename' before the import if it is the case

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Backup SQL using C#](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1849/backup-and-restore-sql-server-databases-programmatically-with-smo/) .It is very helpful ,I dont think there should be any naming issue

also you can do it from sql Server 2005 take a look at [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1436024.aspx)

Comment: I have seen it before, but doesn't it make a .bak file. I would love to use it but I need it to be of type text. If that particular .bak is a text file it would be fine.